# Mercurial: Merge in accidentally created subfolder

Tags: mercurial

TLDR: I seem to have created a separate repository in a subfolder of my main project. How can I combine them?

I have a project folder, let's call it *BOB*. I cloned (`hg clone`) *BOB* to a new folder called *BOB2*. To add new features, I created a subfolder on *BOB2* called *BOB-newfeatures*. I have been working on this *BOB-newfeatures* folder for a while, with many checkins.

Today I realized that somehow I created a separate repository for *BOB-newfeatures* (I hadn't changed anything on *BOB2* main until today so I hadn't noticed that changes weren't being tracked). If I do `hg status` on *BOB2*, it doesn't know about changes in the subfolder and vice versa.

Is there a way to stitch these together? I know I could `hg add` all of the files in *BOB-newfeatures* to *BOB* but then I think I lose all of my checkin history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I reconstructed (I hope) your case, with your names, starting from

```
BOB2>hg log -T "{node|short}\tFiles: {join(files, ', ')}\n"
25a16a8fea5e    Files: Sub/3.txt
bf3c6cacb4a4    Files: 1.txt, 2.txt
ff71a2b1bbe3    Files: 1.txt
```

and nested repo

```
BOB2\BOB-newfeatures>hg log -T "{node|short}\tFiles: {join(files, ', ')}\n"
acac7d413ed2    Files: f1.txt
15a1f9cacf25    Files: f2.txt
f3055921fa01    Files: f1.txt
```

As a additional confirmation of invisibility of `BOB-newfeatures` inside `BOB2`

```
BOB2>hg manifest
1.txt
2.txt
Sub/3.txt
```

---

Method of solving problem - using [Convert extension with `--filemap`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Mercurial) in inversed, compared to Wiki, direction: it's example transform subdir of repo into separate repository, I'll move repository-root into subfolder

- map-file, prepared for conversion

> ```
> rename . BOB-newfeatures
> ```

- conversion

> ```
> hg convert --filemap map z:\BOB2\BOB-newfeatures z:\BOB-newfeatures-conv
> initializing destination z:\BOB-newfeatures-conv repository
> scanning source...
> sorting...
> converting...
> 2 New feature started
> 1 Change 1
> 0 Change 2
> ```

- Testing results

> ```
> BOB-newfeatures-conv>hg log -T "{node|short}\tFiles: {join(files, ', ')}\n"
> a3b2c462a3b9    Files: BOB-newfeatures/f1.txt
> f5f1168cfe2f    Files: BOB-newfeatures/f2.txt
> da27a50a5cb6    Files: BOB-newfeatures/f1.txt
> ```

compare file-paths with log from nested repo, note different hashes for changesets

- Next bad news: you can't just pull from BOB|BOB2 into converted repository missing parts *easy*

> ```
> BOB-newfeatures-conv>hg pull ../BOB2
> pulling from ../BOB2
> searching for changes
> abort: repository is unrelated
> ```

Even with --force (because repositories are *really unrelated* and doesn't share history) you'll get "dirty" combined repository (changes in root and in `BOB-newfeatures/` are two separate lines of changes with own roots and tips)

```
BOB-newfeatures-conv>hg pull ../BOB2 -f
pulling from ../BOB2
searching for changes
warning: repository is unrelated
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 3 changesets with 4 changes to 3 files (+1 heads)
(run 'hg heads' to see heads, 'hg merge' to merge)
```

[image: Force pull result]

And at last step you have to re-link two histories into one common. In my case due to my actions (pulling **to** converted repository with pre-existing history of `BOB-newfeatures`) I had to link 0-1-2 revisions after 3-4-5 (historically earlier changes) and I don't know more elegant way to do it, than again convert (HG->HG) repository, with [`--splicemap`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--splicemap) this time

With log output

```
>hg log -T "{rev} {node}\n"
5 25a16a8fea5e5b4dac42a0a6b2c8e82890c220a3
4 bf3c6cacb4a4c22cb5720ddeab1ec5f8238a98c9
3 ff71a2b1bbe30a56c9dabc9a7ddb2bbccad840af
2 a3b2c462a3b917b3ba58daee3df2632875baee17
1 f5f1168cfe2f4b6c67d0af8a9259665ae2d40bd5
0 da27a50a5cb6246c03c6af7485ac7ffc33e62738
```

splicemap for rule "0 after 5" can be created (with format of oneliner "ChildHash ParentHash")

```
da27a50a5cb6246c03c6af7485ac7ffc33e62738 25a16a8fea5e5b4dac42a0a6b2c8e82890c220a3
```

and last conversion performed

```
>hg convert  --splicemap z:\map z:\BOB-newfeatures-conv z:\BOB3
scanning source...
sorting...
converting...
5 Initial data
4 Changes
3 More changes
2 New feature started
spliced in 25a16a8fea5e5b4dac42a0a6b2c8e82890c220a3 as parents of da27a50a5cb6246c03c6af7485ac7ffc33e62738
1 Change 1
0 Change 2
```

with expected good results

[image: Final Repo]

Comment: The last step would be a lot simpler with `rebase`: If revs `0-2` are the original history and  `1-3` are the imported ones, `hg rebase -s 3 -d 2` should do it.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing and it seemed to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You simply created a separate repository. As such you can pull from that repository like from any other. In this case, in your main repository in *BOB2*, you could do:

```
hg pull ./BOB-newfeatures
```

In order to avoid confusion, I'd first move *BOB-newfeatures* to the same directory level as *BOB2* and pull then giving the new relative path ../BOB-newfeatures; but that's more for cosmetics and to keep your *BOB2* repository clean; strictly speaking it should not be needed.

(Basically you used a feature of hg: you can create a new repo in any sub-path which will be an independent repo which knows nothing of the parent and vice versa. It's used for instance for libraries needed by the main repo but which you do not want to tie directly to your main; they then are found in the expected relative path and it's easy to operate on)

Comment: You can *try* to pull, but read my answer's part, starting with "Next bad news"  - it cost me most spent time to document, copy|paste and decorate with screenshots

Comment: I'm voting this up because I think it probably would have been "good enough" but I ended up using Lazy Badger's solution.